# Unable to load SOS.dll extension in Visual Studion 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, sos

I've started to read some materials on advanced debugging tools and techniques. I use VS2012 Ultimate and the target framework is .NET 4.0. I got to the point where I need to load SOS.dll in the Immediate window during a debug session and it just doesn't work.

I tried these with no luck

- .load sos
- .load sos.dll
- .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll

I always get this message:

> Invalid expression term '.'

So, any idea ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Which debugger do the materials you're reading recommend? I ask because `.load` works with windbg but I don't know if VS2012 supports loading extensions that way.

Comment: @Marc Sherman , I used the information from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)

Comment: I did some further time consuming testing but here it is. Everything works perfectly in VS 2012 RTM, in VS 2012 Update1 but NOT in VS 2012 Update2. I guess Update2 brought a change that messed something up.

Answer (score 7):

You can change this setting to work around the issue:

Under Tools->Option->Debugging->General, check the box labeled "Managed Compatibility Mode."

That fixes the issue for me. This workaround is from http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789601/-load-sos-does-not-works#

Comment: Worked for me once I restarted the debug session.

Comment: VS2015 -> "Error during command: Warning. Extension is using a callback which Visual Studio does not implement."

Answer (score 2):

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
```

works for me with VS2012 Update3

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error loading was a matter of need to use path separator as '\\' (Windbg).