# .loadby sos.dll clr yields Invalid expression term '.' in Immediate window

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I wanted to use this so it locates the proper version, as been recommended in many articles.   I have checked every  question referring to "Invalid expression term '.'" and none refer to this when attempting loadby.  I tried various flavors of the command, like  .loadby sos clr,  .loadby sos.dll clr, none work.

If I try :  .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll it returns "Error during command: Warning. Extension is using a callback which Visual Studio does not implement."

If I try :  .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll it returns "Error during command: extension c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll could not load (error 193)" : happens in AnyCpu or x64 platform setting

VS2013, Net 4.5, 64 bit laptop, using AnyCpu platform, c# Console application

Any ideas?  Not sure what to try now.  Thank you in advance

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827205/why-does-not-load-sos-dll-in-vs-2013) especially Hans' answer.  The last time I ever successfully used SOS in VS was with version 2010.

Comment: @Chris O - appreciate your comeback!  I saw this one earlier as well.  I guess its a dead end .... time to go a different route